# How do I select the most appropriate degree param with PolynomialFeatures?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have time series code that generates a linear and quadratic trend.  I am confused on what to select for the `degree` parameter.  I see the following definition:

`Within scikit-learn's PolynomialFeatures, when the argument degree is passed, all terms up to that degree are created.`

I'm just not understanding that definition.  Is there an explanation that uses simple math?  How can I make sure I'm using the best degree?

Here is my code if you want it for a sample.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm                                                                                                                          

import statsmodels.formula.api as smf                                                                                                                 

import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt
import random
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline


y = [5*np.random.normal() for j in range(50)] + [30 + 5 * np.random.normal() for j in range(50)] +  [50 + 5 * np.random.normal() for j in range(50)] +  [20 + 5 * np.random.normal() for j in range(50)]
X = [x for x in range(len(y))]
X = np.reshape(X, (len(X), 1))

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
trend = model.predict(X)

model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(2), Ridge())
model.fit(X, y)
quadratic = model.predict(X)

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(15, 9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(trend, label="Linear Trend")
ax.plot(quadratic, label="Quadratic Trend")
ax.plot(X, y, label='Time Series')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use **2** for the degree; the linear component will be subsumed in the quadratic.  For instance, if your computed linear component is `2x - 5` and the quadratic is `3x^2 + x + 1`, then what you get back from the function will be the sum, `3x^2 + 3x + 4`.

Comment: what would be the effect of changing degree to 3 or 4?  Or are you saying it should always be 2?

Comment: To determine this, you have to experiment with various degrees to obtain the best fit for your purposes.  If your data fits perfectly to a quadratic, then higher degrees will get you only zero coefficients for the higher degrees of **x**.  If your data fits the quadratic *very* well, then the higher degrees will give you very small higher coefficients.

Comment: The cases you want to avoid (by experimentation) are where *you* know your data is relatively smooth, but a few outliers *seriously* change fitting at higher degrees.  You can get wild swings outside the "main channel" of the data in an attempt to include those wayward points.